# Stop YouTube embed video in UIWebView using Done button

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I have a UIWebView that displays a YouTube video. This works correctly.

```
NSString *urlYouTube = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.youtube.com/embed/%@?rel=0&showinfo=0",idURL];
[webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:video.urlYouTube]]];
```

The video is displayed in full screen. However, when I click the Done button while the video is running, the video doesn't close. I must click on the pause button and then the Done button to exit the video.

Should I implement a method via UIWebViewDelegate ?

Answer (score 0):

Use this code.

```
-(void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
  {
    [webView loadHTMLString:nil baseURL:nil];
  }
```

Comment: When I launch video, viewWillDisappear method is fired. The video stops before even started. And `[webView loadHTMLString:nil baseURL:nil];` hides my video, it's blank.

Comment: why are you play video in UIwebview use MPMovieController for it.

Comment: MPMoviePlayerController doesn't work because youtube does not expose direct links to the video files.

Answer (score 0):

I was successful using this:

```
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@""]];
[webView loadRequest:request];
```